# Module not found yarn 2 when bundling with webpack

Tags: webpack, yarn-v2

I'm trying to use yarn 2 to build an application with webpack and I get this error when building with both webpack 4 and `pnp-webpack-plugin` and webpack 5:

```
(node:415) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error on webpack build: ../lib/core/lib/nudash.js
Module not found: Error: Something that got detected as your top-level application (because it doesn't seem to belong to any package) tried to access a package that is not declared in your dependencies

Required package: core-js (via "core-js/modules/web.dom-collections.iterator")
Required by: /usr/src/app/lib/core/lib/nudash.js
```

I don't see what's causing this issue and it works with yarn 1, so what can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need to install the package core-js.

In the terminal in the root folder of your project (same place you ran webpack build) run

```
yarn add core-js
```

Comment: I currently have 3 versions of `core-js` installed: `3.6.4`, `2.6.11` and `1.2.7`